# How can I read data with my custom encode?

Tags: sql-server

I have a heavy CSV file and I read and insert on sql server table with bulk insert but my character should be encode with this example:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(1256)
```

I want create temp table for first read with Bulk insert into that,and encode temp table and insert into other table.
How can I do this? Thanks for pay attention to my problem.

Comment: Read aboud [collation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks,can you say a one example?i read that link but cant understand

Comment: Actually, nvarchar should be fine with keeping your encoding.

Comment: you are using what ? C# , SQL Server ?

Comment: You may be able to use the import export utility built into SQL Server and write a query to get the information you want in the correct format.

Comment: Can you give the bulk insert Script Or bcp command

Comment: @WesPalmer I assume your talking about the Import Export utility within SSMS tools? I don't think SQL server has a front end as such?

Comment: That is the one that I am referring to.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411336/how-to-set-encoding-parameter-for-sql-server-bulk-statement

Answer (score 0):

```
BULK INSERT myTable
FROM 'd:\myFile.csv'
WITH(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    CODEPAGE = '1256'
  );
```